# insert using a select from other table with mysql

Tags: mysql

Trying to insert into other table with the following command but it is neither throwing an error nor inserting:

```
INSERT INTO orderlines(orderLineItemName,orderLineItemnotes,itemID,itemPriceNormal,categoryID
,regionID,orderLineItemQuantity,orderLineItemPriceUnit,orderLineItemDiscount,orderLineItemSubTotal,
orderLineItemTotalTax 
,orderLineItemStatus,userID,orderLineItemDateCreated,orderLineItemDateUpdated,ordercode) 
SELECT quoteLineItemName, quoteLineItemnotes, itemID, itemPriceNormal, categoryID, regionID, 
quoteLineItemQuantity, quoteLineItemPriceUnit, quoteLineItemDiscount, quoteLineItemSubTotal, 
quoteLineItemTotalTax, quoteLineItemStatus, userID, quoteLineItemDateCreated, quoteLineItemDateUpdated,
'Complete' as orderstatus 
FROM quoteslines 
WHERE quotelineitemid = 1
```

Comment: Does select part on its own return any rows?

Comment: yes it returns 1 row

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO orderlines
SELECT quoteLineItemName, quoteLineItemnotes, itemID, itemPriceNormal, categoryID, regionID, 
quoteLineItemQuantity, quoteLineItemPriceUnit, quoteLineItemDiscount, quoteLineItemSubTotal, 
quoteLineItemTotalTax, quoteLineItemStatus, userID, quoteLineItemDateCreated,              quoteLineItemDateUpdated,
 'Complete' as orderstatus 
FROM quoteslines 
WHERE quotelineitemid = 1
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, you are right. fixed error

Comment: So how is this now different from the code in the question (apart from not listing the target columns)

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to use "**'Complete' as orderstatus**" for the last column value. I don't think so. If you want to enter value "Complete" in the last column, please try below.

```
INSERT INTO orderlines(orderLineItemName,orderLineItemnotes,itemID,itemPriceNormal,categoryID
,regionID,orderLineItemQuantity,orderLineItemPriceUnit,orderLineItemDiscount,orderLineItemSubTotal,
orderLineItemTotalTax 
,orderLineItemStatus,userID,orderLineItemDateCreated,orderLineItemDateUpdated,ordercode) 

SELECT quoteLineItemName, quoteLineItemnotes, itemID, itemPriceNormal, categoryID, regionID, 
quoteLineItemQuantity, quoteLineItemPriceUnit, quoteLineItemDiscount, quoteLineItemSubTotal, 
quoteLineItemTotalTax, quoteLineItemStatus, userID, quoteLineItemDateCreated, quoteLineItemDateUpdated,
'Complete'
FROM quoteslines 
WHERE quotelineitemid = 1
```

Comment: This will only work if there is a column `Complete` in the table `quoteslines`. How do you know there is such a column?

Comment: So how is this different now to the original statement?

Comment: from the select query we are getting the data only to insert into orderlines table. we need only the column data not column name of the quoteslines table.